# Ramda — Toggle properties of an object based on an allow list

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have the following case with one Object and one Array:

```
const currenObject = {
  errors: false,
  values: false,
  warnings: false,
};

const template = ['values', 'warnings'];
```

How to map over `currentObject` and if property is present in the `template` array to change the corresponding property to `true`. So the above example should produce:

```
const currenObject = {
  errors: false,
  values: true,
  warnings: true,
};
```

That is trivial with vanilla javascript but the goal is to achieve it with **Ramda JS**.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers assume you want to set the relevant values to `true`.

But the title implies that you want to toggle their current boolean values.  Here's a version that does so, which will be more obvious if I switch one of the input's target values to start as `true`.

```js
const toggleFields = compose (evolve, compose (mergeAll, map (objOf (__, not))))

const currentObject = {
  errors: false,
  values: true,
  warnings: false,
};

const template = ['values', 'warnings'];

console .log (toggleFields (template) (currentObject))
// => {
//      errors: false,  // ignored
//      values: false,  // toggled from true
//      warnings: true  // toggled from false
//    }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {compose, evolve, mergeAll, map, objOf, __, not} = R </script>
```

We work by turning `['values', 'warnings']` into

```js
evolve ({
  values: not,
  warnings: not
})
```

where [`not`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#not) is Ramda's boolean-toggle function and [`evolve`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) takes a configuration object mapping names to transformer functions and returns a function which takes an object and clones it, transforming any of the specified properties by the appropriate function.  Then we simply call this function with our source object.

If we happened to be in a character drought, we could use Ramda curried, binary composition function, [`o`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#o), in place of the venerable [`compose`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) itself:

```js
const toggleFields = o (evolve, o (mergeAll, map (objOf (__, not))))
```

Depending on taste, we might also replace `objOf (__, not)` with `flip (objOf) (not)`.

### Derivation

This version seems quite dense.  I originally wrote it like this:

```js
const fn = (template) => (currentObject) => evolve (pipe (
  map (objOf (__, not)),
  mergeAll
) (template)) (currentObject)
```

But here, if we squint a little, we can see this as this form:

```js
(x) => (y) => f (g (x)) (y)
```

with `x` standing for `template`, `y` for `currentObject`, `f` for `evolve`, and `g` for everything else.

And whenever we have a final parameter that is only applied at the end of the body, we can simply eliminate it, so that is the same as

```js
(x) => f (g (x))
```

But that is just the composition of `f` and `g`.  So we can write this as

```js
compose (f, g)
```

and substituting back in our original we get

```js
compose (
  evolve,
  pipe (map (objOf (__, not)), mergeAll) 
)
```

I usually don't like to mix `compose` and `pipe` in a pipeline.  I use `compose` for one-liners and `pipe` for longer functions; this is starting to look like a one-liner to me.  So we swap the order of the `map` and `mergeAll` and switch to `compose`, yielding this:

```js
compose (evolve, compose (mergeAll, map (objOf (__, not)))
```

### Vanilla

As a founder and principal author of Ramda, I am actually the one often suggesting that people are trying to apply it in places they don't need.  But here I think that this version is quite a bit cleaner than the first vanilla JS version I come up with:

```js
const toggle = (template) => (currentObject) =>
  Object .fromEntries (
    Object .entries (currentObject) 
      .map (([k, v]) => [k, template .includes (k) ? !v : v] )
  )
```

It's not that such is bad, and I wouldn't introduce Ramda just for this slight improvement.  But if I was already using Ramda, then the Ramda version does seem an improvement.

Comment: i like the squinting exercise in this answer. it's useful to practice seeing the "shape" of a function or process. like tetris, each tetrimino captures an essence that makes it unique and determines how it will fit with other pieces.

Comment: Very thorough explanation Scott. Thank you for your help. Ramda is great and very interesting to explore.

Answer (score 2):

Map the `template` to array of `[key, T]`, convert to object using R.fromPairs, and then use R.evolve to create the updated object:

```js
const { pipe, map, of, append, T, fromPairs, evolve } = R;

const fn = pipe(map(pipe(of, append(T))), fromPairs, evolve);

const currenObject = {
  errors: false,
  values: false,
  warnings: false,
};

const template = ['values', 'warnings'];

const result = fn(template)(currenObject);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Again, good explanation Ori. For me, that is new approach - unifying the interfaces so to say. I made similar thing with vanilla js. Thank you again for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**with modules**

Here's a module-based approach to the problem -

```js
// obj.js

function get (t, k) {
  return t[k]
}

function set (t, k, v) {
  return { ...t, [k]: v }
}

function update (t, k, f) {
  return set(t, k, f(get(t, k)))
}

export { get, set, update }
```

We established generic ways to interact with objects. Now we can easily write `toggle` using `update` -

```js
// main.js

import { update } from "./obj.js"

function toggle (t, k) {
  return update(t, k, (v = false) => !v)
}

const input =
  { errors: false, values: false, warnings: false }
  
const output =
  ["values", "warnings"].reduce(toggle, input)

console.log(output)
```

```js
{
  errors: false,
  values: true,
  warnings: true
}
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your browser -

```js
function get (t, k) {
  return t[k]
}

function set (t, k, v) {
  return { ...t, [k]: v }
}

function update (t, k, f) {
  return set(t, k, f(get(t, k)))
}

function toggle (t, k) {
  return update(t, k, v => !v)
}

const input =
  { errors: false, values: false, warnings: false }
  
const output =
  ["values", "warnings"].reduce(toggle, input)

console.log(output)
```

**with ramda**

If you prefer Ramda, there are exact (or near) equivalents -

| obj module | ramda |
| --- | --- |
| `obj.get` | [R.prop](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#prop) |
| `obj.set` | [R.assoc](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc) |
| `obj.update` | [R.evolve](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) |

Knowing this, we can choose to use ramda directly or we could implement `obj` module using ramda itself -

```js
// obj

import { assoc, prop, evolve } from "ramda"

function get (t, k) {
  return prop(k, t)
}

function set (t, k, v) {
  return assoc(k, v, t)
}

function update (t, k, f) {
  return evolve({ [k]: f }, t)
}

export { get, set, update }
```

The difference here is users of `obj` have no idea ramda is being used behind the curtains. This is a useful way to design custom modules that may fit your program or patterns more effectively, while simultaneously taking advantage of the strengths of other libraries or patterns.

Comment: Very nice!  I might argue that Ramda's closest equivalent to your `update` is a combination of `lensProp` and `over`, but that would involve a detour into the wonderful world of lenses, perhaps overkill.  This does demonstrate that Ramda is probably missing a function; we'll have to think about it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet i was torn on the lens matter and opted for simplicity. i'm happy to help discover more ways ramda can be made more useful ^^

Comment: I'd love your opinion on whether there is an appropriate type unifying Objects and Arrays for such a function.  `R.adjust` is similar for arrays.  I'm trying to think through an appropriate supertype that unifies them, similar to how they are both Functors and therefore a single `map` covers both.  Here it would have to have identity and composition laws (∀ k, `adj k  id x ~> x` and `adj k f (adj k g x) ~= adj k (f . g) x`), and is quite Functor-like, but there would need to be something about the use of a Key. Is this worth pursuing directly or does it just take us down the road to Lenses?

Comment: due to javascript's dynamic typing, i don't see clean unifying type for both, especially because arrays are numerically indexed and objects are string indexed. but in practice, javascript is loosey-goosey and allows to access arrays and objects using mixed types. in addition, i can see that objects would need the functional to be `a -> b` but if you wanted to enforce homogeneous arrays, the functional must be `a -> a`, causing a conflict.  of course implementation of `adj` that supports both is easy, however typing it seems almost impossible in this case.

Comment: (cont) i would probably just write it as two separate overloaded types: `adj number ('a -> 'a) ['a] -> ['a]` *and* `adj string (* -> *) {string: *} -> {string: *}`

Comment: You''re probably right.  I haven't given this any more thought since I wrote that, but looking back I don't see a good reason to pursue it.  I will probably try to get in an equivalent simple function though that doesn't require lenses for this task, though.  Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: anytime, i always appreciate our discussions

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```js
const obj = { errors: false, values: false, warnings: false };
const tpl = ['values', 'warnings'];
```

You can cherry-pick properties in `obj` from `tpl` with:

```js
pick(tpl, obj);
//=> {"values": false, "warnings": false}
```

And set them to `true` with:

```js
map(T, pick(tpl, obj));
//=> {"values": true, "warnings": true}
```

What's left is to merge that object into the original one:

```js
const toggle = curry((t, o) => mergeRight(o, map(T, pick(t, o))));

toggle(tpl, obj);
//=> {"errors": false, "values": true, "warnings": true}
```